# How do you control which field iOS/Android will focus to when you click next while you're filling out a form?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html

The scenario is that I have a modal with a multi-step process that I show one at a time, but not every step has a form field.

So when I'm ready to move on from `Step 1` (which has a form field) and I click the next helper icon in the keyboard's toolbar (a function of iOS) it forwards me to an unavailable/translucent field in `Step 4`.

Step 1: Ask for age
Step 2: Choose a gender (these are LI elements)
Step 3: Choose interests (these are also LI elements)
Step 4: Enter a name

I've tried `tabIndex`, but that doesn't have any affect.

I'm not certain this is even possible since this is really an iOS control. If it's not possible can you hide that?

The undesirable fix would be to do a check when the user has focused on the `Step 4` field and if the elements in `Step 3` and `Step 4` have not been chosen focus the user on the applicable previous step.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,it's a same order of html structure.
So if you want to change the order, change html.
If you can't or You can't avoid the issue by changing the html file for some reason such as complicated html structure causing the issue or something.
Below code is how to disable `<prev>` `<next>` buttons of IOS keyboard.

html

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="number" />
<input type="date" />
<input type="time" />
<input type="tel" />
```

javascript(jquery)

```
$("input").on("touchstart",function(e){
  _$activeElem = $(this);
  //readonly disables next/prev buttons. so when user tap input field,turns any other input into readonly
  //You cannot use focus here because keyboard shows up before focus fired,you need to use touchstart instead.
  $("input").each(function(){
    if($(this).get(0) === _$activeElem.get(0)){
      _$activeElem.removeAttr("readonly");
      $(this).one("blur",function(){
        $(this).attr("readonly","readonly");
      });
      return;
    }else{
      $(this).attr("readonly","readonly");
    }
  });
  //remove readonly property on blur
  $("input").on("blur",function(){
    if($("input:not([readonly])").length === -1){
      $("input").removeAttr("readonly");
    }
  });
});
```

and make `readonly` input look like normal input field by CSS.